# C# if condition format

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, .net-core, conditional-statements

I have a condition like this.

`if (data.Data != null && data.Data.Any())`

I wanna change like this.

`if (data is not { Data: null } && data is { Data: ... })`

How can we check if there are elements within the 'Data' which is a list in this format? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest to simplify like this: `if(data.Data?.Any() ?? false)`

Comment: Or `if (data.Data?.Any() == true)`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I usually dislike `== true` but it is (one of a very few) value use cases for it. I still find my suggestion more readable, because it's harder to get wrong - in your suggestion one can easily overlook the `?` before the `.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the type of `Data` is a `List` or an array or things like that, you can use the new [list patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/list-patterns):

```
if (data is { Data: [_, ..] }) {
```

You use `_` to match any element, and the `..` matches the rest of the elements. Nulls are handled automatically by the patterns (they won't be matched).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that list patterns is only supported since c# 11 (which is the latest version released at the time this comment is written)

Answer (score 2):

What I have seen and done before:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this List<T> list)
       => list is null || list.Count == 0;
}
```

Usage: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ew09B8)

```
List<string> list = null;
Console.WriteLine(list.IsNullOrEmpty()); // true
list = new();
Console.WriteLine(list.IsNullOrEmpty()); // true
list.Add("");
Console.WriteLine(list.IsNullOrEmpty()); // false
```

---

You could also combine that with [@Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77437644/982149) (upvoted it myself):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasData(this WhateverTypeDataIs data)
       => data is { Data: [_, ..] };
}
```

which makes for a more readable developer experience:

```
if (data.HasData()) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In C#, the `is` keyword combined with property patterns can be used for null checks, but it's not designed to check for collection contents like whether a list is empty or not.

Your first line of code:

```cs
if (data.Data != null && data.Data.Any())
```

This is checking if `Data` is not null and that `Data` has any elements.

If you want to use pattern matching with `is` to ensure `Data` is not null, you could write:

```cs
if (data is { Data: {} } && data.Data.Any())
```

Here `{ Data: {} }` is using a property pattern to match a non-null `Data` property. However, you cannot use pattern matching to check if `Data` has any elements. The `Any()` method is still required to check if the collection has at least one element.

So the equivalent check with `is` and property pattern would be:

```cs
if (data is { Data: {} dataItems } && dataItems.Any())
```

This will assign `Data` to `dataItems` if `Data` is not null and then use the `Any()` method to check if there are any items in the list. However, note that this code is more verbose and does not add any benefit over your original condition; it's just a different syntax to accomplish the same thing.

The `is` keyword with patterns is more useful when you want to do more complex type checks and decompositions. For simple null checks and checking if collections have items, the `!= null` and `.Any()` checks are more idiomatic and clearer.

Comment: gibbiddy doesn't know about list patterns, yet, it seems ...